Toggle component visibility in React by clicking it
I want to do as follows:

if the component is visible, then clicking off of it hides the component
if the component is hidden, the clicking on it (or I guess whatever area on the screen it would take up if it was visible) shows the component.

How can I do this? I'm trying to do this with a MUI textfield using the sx prop and a visibility state that toggles when you click on it, but the onClick doesn't seem to trigger if the component has visibility: hidden.
EDIT: the important thing to note is that I want to toggle the component's visibility by clicking on the component itself. Using the display and visibility properties do not work, because after you toggle them to be invisible, you can't toggle them to be visible again by clicking it, because the component itself does not seem to be there anymore. Therefore a solution using that does not work, because it assumes the use of a different component such as a button.

You can use a wrapper component to achieve the desired functionality. This component manages the visibility state and handles clicks. Please share snippets of your code or a link to codepen so that we can see what actually is happening with your code.

Does this answer your question? React toggle div visibility on button click

Use the searchbar, please

@SoZettaSho no I don't think it answers my question and yes I did search for answers before posting and came across similar posts to the one you linked. The issue is they all show how to change visibility using an external component which is always visible. I want to toggle the component's visibility by clicking on the component itself. Using the display and visibility properties do not work, because after you toggle them to be invisible, you can't toggle them to be visible again by clicking it, because the component itself does not seem to be there anymore.

Does this answer your question? React - show/hide element on click

Does this answer your question? How to show and hide an element on button click in React?

Does this answer your question? How to manage the click event to show/hide certain element in React?

Does this answer your question? Show or hide element in React

You can use opacity in style to control the component visibility.

Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, a property that changes visibility without removing the element itself which would cause the onClick function to not trigger anymore.
